# How can I fix a small leak in PVC pipe?

Tags: leaks

I installed a new sink this weekend, and as a result I had to redo the drain pipes.

At the joint to a 90 degree elbow and the Y there is a small leak.  The pipes are 2" diameter, and I fear that I did not allow them to set enough or I did not put enough glue on them.  I typical work with PVC involves irrigation systems that are a much smaller diameter.

Given that I only have access from the outside is there a way to fix the small leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to properly fix it is to redo that section of pipe.  Anything else is just a band aid that will likely fail in the near future.

The leak is probably worse than you think since drains are not under any pressure.  If you don't fix it, what will likely happen is that as the drain slowly clogs, the leak will get worse as  it has no where to go but out through the leak.

Comment: Best answer, although it is not the one I want.

Comment: Mike Holmes would rip your entire house down to fix it :P